# Configurating Interface to use with Framework

Tags: java, reflection, reflections

I'm currently developing a framework where I'll provide an Interface that the user should implement in his application for configuration purposes. The user should ne able to implement a `getTargetUsername()` that will be used in the framework side.

What I'm trying to achieve a is pretty much what [Togglez](http://www.togglz.org/documentation/configuration.html) do:

```
public class MyTogglzConfiguration implements TogglzConfig {

    public Class<? extends Feature> getFeatureClass() {
        return MyFeatures.class;
    }

}
```

My problem is that I'm struggling to find how should I lookup for the class that is implementing my configuration interface. And call the `getTargetUsername()` method inside the framework.

---

### What I've tryed so far:

I'm currently trying to do the trick using `Reflections`, but I'm not sure this is the right approach, since I don't know if this is looking only inside my framework package or it will search inside a prject that add it as a dependency.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections();
Set<Class<? extends FrameworkConfig>> configurations = reflections.getSubTypesOf(FrameworkConfig.class);

//Getting the Class thats is implementing here
Object c = configurations.toArray()[0];
```

I'm being able to get the right Class with the above code but I acctually can't call `getTargetUsername()`.

Comment: Sounds like you're developing a plugin framework. There are some libs out there that you may find useful: http://jpf.sourceforge.net/index.html, https://www.osgi.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `configurations` set already contains all relevant classes, then the first step is to create a new instace of that class.

```
Class<? extends FrameworkConfig> clazz = configurations.iterator().next();
FrameworkConfig myInstance = clazz.newInstance();
```

After that you can call the method as usual:

```
Class<? extends Feature> featureClass = myInstance.getFeatureClass();
```

After that you can do whatever you want with that information. But I assume, that you will create a new instance of that class also:

```
Feature myFeature = featureClass.newInstance();
```

Now you can interact with that instance:

```
myFeature.foo();
```

All this code assumes, that bot classes `FrameworkConfig` and `Feature` have a default constructor - a public constructor without parameters.

Comment: Thanks for yor answer. My only concern here still remains on execution time for `reflection.getSubTypesOf()`. I'm getting almost 4 secounds to run it inside a big project. I know i must enforce that this runs only once, when application starts. But either way, its a considerable time.

Comment: I don't know google-reflections and but I assume, that it has to load every class on the classpath and then scan it just to compute your subtype predicate. Check that by printing the apprpriate class-names in the first run and replacing `getSubTypesOf()` with a static list of these classes in a second run. This will only load the required classes. If that time is good enough, then just go to the @tan9 solution, because that will not require a classpath scan.

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to achieve it is by using [java.util.ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html).

Implementer "register" the fully qualified class name of his/her implementation in:

> `META-INF/services/package.to.YourInterface`

You can then load the implementation this way:

```java
ServiceLoader.load(YourInterface.class).iterator().next().getTargetUsername();
```